# Languages where ¬(a = b) and (a ≠ b) can be different

Tags: language-agnostic

In C++ one can overload the `==` and `!=` operators for user types, but the language doesn't care how you do it. You can overload both to return `true` no matter what, so `!(a==b)` and `(a!=b)` don't necessarily have to evaluate to the same thing. How many other languages have a situation where `¬(a = b)` and `(a ≠ b)` can be different? Is it a common thing?

It's not just an issue of overloads, but of strange corner cases even for primitive types. NaN in C and C++ doesn't compare equal to anything, including NaN. It is true that NaN != NaN in C, but maybe there are similar cases in other languages that cause `¬(a = b)` and `(a ≠ b)` to be different?

Comment: Just  because you CAN do it in C++ doesn't mean you ever, ever should...

Comment: I know you can do it in Ruby!

Comment: I'd also be tempted to add.. any language where you can overload either the == or the != operator. Or is that too obv?

Comment: There should be some cases in JavaScript, I guess.

Comment: @Arth of course in C++ you can also create a `FakeBool` class, overload the `==` and `!=` operators to work correctly but return a `FakeBool`, and then overload `operator!` to `return *this;`

Answer (score 2):

[Guy L. Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele) famously said

> ...the ability to define your own operator functions means that a simple statement such as x=a+b; in an inner loop might involve the sending of e-mail to Afghanistan.

And as corsiKa says, just because you can do it, doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that Python and Ruby can and Java and PHP can not. (In Java `==` determines if two objects are the same thing in memory, not just semantically equivalent values. In PHP...never mind.) I'd also imagine that Lisp and JS can and C can not, but that's a bit more speculative.

It's nothing unusual to be able to overload operators. It is very rare for `!(a==b)` and `(a!=b)` to have different results though.

Comment: Java only allows the positive to be changed: `Equals` and no way to overload the negated form.

Comment: Yes, you can reasonably override `==` and `!=` to generate something else than a Boolean result (maybe an SQL condition or whatnot), but it's counterproductive to break the logic so that `!(a == b)` is not equal to `(a != b)`.